# How to fix crossed bootstrap navigation links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm having trouble getting the bootstrap navigation to look like the example here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/WRERX#comments

When I run my code in several different browsers (Opera, Safari, etc) it looks nothing like the example.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if anyone knows a clever hack to fix this issue but the issue is the links are overlapping each other and they also don't have the correct styling that they should have.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse" role="navigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/160x80" /></a>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
    .navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
          
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
            <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.
            </p>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```